# Can't change navbar-brand image position to be in vertically centered in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So I'm trying to build a site and I'm trying to insert a picture in the navbar where the navbar-brand is but the picture is off-centre.

How to get the picture to be placed in the middle vertically or have the navbar wrap around it?

[image: navbar]

```css
.navbar {
 background-color: #FE0000;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-style: none;

}

.navbar-brand > img {
 display: inline-block;
 position: top;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 0px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md scrolling-navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4? The navbar looks like a mix of both.

Comment: @Md.Sifatul Islam I approved your edit. However, please note that quote markdown (">")  is only for quotes. It should not be used for emphasis or embellishment.

Answer (score 2):

Bydefault `bootstrap` navbar come with some padding/height, just update your CSS with zero padding and required height to set this

```
.navbar-brand {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```